# Multi-Threading and Listbox

Tags: c#, multithreading

What I'm trying to do is get and remove the first item in a listbox with multiple threads, though I need to keep the threads from using the same item.

Ex: Thread 1 and 2 both grab 1, and attempt to remove 1, but in the process, both threads use the same variable, and both 1 and 2 are removed since I'm using removeat(0).

### Listbox for Ex

1

2

How would I go about managing the threads so that they don't use / remove the wrong variables?

Comment: No, you cannot, just only and only one UI Thread can modify UI

Comment: You can add a unique ID to each item and remove based on that ID instead of its position.

Comment: +1 for @CuongLe - Only the UI thread will be able to update your ListBox. Depending on your setup you might be able to trigger an event in your threads that you could then dispatch to the UI thread. This might also be the point where you want to put your guard for removing the wrong item. Or you could dispatch directly from your threads, either way the actual removal will have to happen in the UI thread and at that point you have an opportunity to guard against removing the wrong item.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the particular item in the list and remove it.............

```
 foreach (string item in toRemove)
 {
   listbox.Remove(item);
 }
```

OR.........

If you are assigning a datasource to it then add one more UNIQUE column like Primary Key and on the basis of that unique column you can remove item from LISTBOX

Comment: the removing really isn't my main problem, main problem is the same variable being used in two different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You could lock the threads on a reference (maybe the list ?) for the whole process of

1. Finding the item
2. removing the item if it was found

HTH

Comment: In that case it would probably be just as efficient using a single thread (and since this is a UI component, then that's really the only option).

Answer (score 0):

Use Lock when you access your listbox items. Use the same object for locking everywhere.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx